# retriving data from flash builder http service

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

I am very new to flex and flash builder. What I am trying to do is connect to a http data service and retrieve data from it.

All the tutorials I have found go through the process of setting up the data service and taking the response and putting it in a grid.

Wheat I am not understanding (and it is probably really simple.) is how to take the response and instead of putting it into a data grid, just store the results in variables for later use.

If someone can help me get going with this, it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first create a variable for you to store the results:

```
public var results : ArrayCollection;
```

Then in you result handler, just store the values:

```
protected function resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void{
  results = new ArrayCollection(event.result as Array);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Slight difference to Flextras's answer:

```
public var results : ArrayCollection;
```

Then in you result handler, just store the values:

```
protected function resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void{
    if(event.result is Array) 
        results = new ArrayCollection(event.result as Array);
    else if(event.result is IList)
        results = new ArrayCollection(event.result.source);
    else 
        results = new ArrayCollection([event.result]);
}
```

Now usually this checking of the type of the `event.result` is not required because most webservices will be consistent in the return type. So, all you need to do is debug the application and insert a breakpoint at the entry to the `resultHandler` function. Then watch the `event.result` and note its type, and depending on that, retain the corresponding line of code.

P.S.: `IList` is an interface implemented by the `ArrayCollection`, `ArrayList`, and many other classes, so if the result is one of these classes, then you need to keep that line.

Comment: In my experience it is very rare that "most webservices will be consistent in the return type."  I have worked with services that return XML, arrays, string values, or integers.  Granted my answer, assumed an array was returned and that you wanted to store it as an ArrayCollection; that was primary b/c the original poster mentioned using the results as a dataProvider.